# Where do I find Google Chrome's logs on a mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, logging

My flash plugin keeps crashing and I would like to find the cause. Where are Chrome's logs located? I don't see any information on Google's site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Mac, Chrome’s [crash dumps](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines/reporting-crash-bug#TOC-Mac) are located in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Crash Reports`.

Comment: Folder does not exist chrome 108.0.5359.124